# Datetime(6) None Web2py + MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, web2py, nonetype

I'm working with web2py using a MySQL db. 
In my db I have a table with a field of type datetime(6).
When I do a 'db(query).select()' on the table with the datetime field I get a none value instead of the correct value setted in the MySQL db.

If I change the MySQL table field to use datetime instead of datetime(6) the query works and I get the datetime value with seconds precision.

Any ideas of what may be happening?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and web2py 2.14.6 with MySQL 5.7.12

Thanks to all.

Comment: Perhaps it is related to [this bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/mysql-python/bugs/325/) in the MySQLdb driver. Do you have the latest version of the driver (not sure if/when the bug was fixed)? Does it work if you use the MySQLdb driver directly, outside of the web2py DAL? If not, maybe switch to pymsql or mysqlconnector, which web2py also supports.

Comment: The web2py [book](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#The-database-abstraction-layer) states that DAL uses pymysql and that it should ship with web2py. For some reason, pymysql wasn't installed and simply installing it with 'pip install pymysql' solved the problem. Your comment was essential to me to see this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, web2py does come with pymysql: https://github.com/web2py/web2py/tree/master/gluon/contrib/pymysql. By default, though, it will use the MySQLdb driver if it is present, unless you explicitly tell it to use pymysql via the connection string or the `adapter_args` parameter.